# Create a virtual server which use the full power of my GPU

Tags: raytracing

i dont know if i can create a virtual server (with vmware, virtual box or with something like that), and if i can use the full power of my graph (i have a nvidia rtx 2080 super) or if I'm going to lose some power of this gpu.

or which tools can i use?

```
print('please dont close this i need to know the answer')
```

So, can i connect a rtx 2080 super to my server, and create a virtual server with the full power of the graph?? i need to know if I can use the full power of the graph or not, for example, i want to create a virtual server for play videogames in every place, so i only have to connect to this server and play (this is only an example) so this server will use the full power of the graph nvidai rtx 2080 super or not?? Thanks so much, and i cant try this if i dont know if it will works, because i have to buy the graph.